# What are the benefits of Windows 7 for software developers?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to make the case for upgrading my development machine to Windows 7 - I'm currently on Windows XP 32bit.

I've already identified the fact that moving to a 64bit OS should help performance by allowing  me to max out the amount of RAM in my system.

But what other features new to Windows 7 are a boon to software developers?

Comment: more clever I am a PC / I am a MAC commercials

Comment: Shit, I'm still wondering why I should move off of 2000!  Also, punchcards.

Comment: Why's this closed?  We can't talk about the WDK and new features in kernel-land only present in Win7?

Comment: This is certainly a "real" question.  I can only imagine it being properly closed as "not programming related".  However, in my book, deciding on the right tools for the job is programming related.

Comment: PS - The replies that made it in before closing are useful to me personally.

Answer (score 4):

On modern hardware, it is faster than both XP and Vista in just about every task -- booting, copying, launching programs.  It also uses multicore CPUs more efficiently than XP.

I've also found that the search feature on the new Start menu saves a ton of time that I usually spent looking for files in XP.

As far as actual development goes, I know Eclipse has a native 64-bit version.  Visual Studio doesn't have one though.  In any case, 32 vs. 64 bit probably won't have any noticeable performance differences when you're using your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

64bit will only really help you if you go beyond 4GB mark.

I don't know what you development platform is, but it would be probably fair to say that all new platforms will be thoroughly tested on Windows 7.

Also, you may want to read this article if you are interested in what Windows 7 gives you as a developer:

http://sdtimes.com/link/33856

Comment: +1: good link not only what features you're going to use but which features you could use when developing applications

Comment: Be aware that 64 bit operating systems generally require more memory for the same task because "thing" are bigger (pointers, integers).  One estimate I read is that a given Java program requires 50% more memory (average case) when running on a 64-bit JVM vs. a 32-bit JVM.

Answer (score 1):

It's my impression that many IT departments eschewed upgrading to Vista because of compatibility worries but will probably embrace Win7. That said it would behoove a programming shoppe to develop for Win7 simply because that market segment will grow. It's still early but i doubt Redmond would produce two stinkers in a row... Well, Win98 and Me were quite the tandem...

Comment: between these 2 there was Win98SE which was pretty good in my view.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the new Explorer and start menu search quite useful (most of this was already in Vista)

Also, it will encourage you to take advantage of Windows 7's [new taskbar features](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/06/18/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-application-id.aspx) in your programs.